# Shipping Method change that into Shipping charges

Tags: magento

In Payment path  there is step called Shipping Method i want to change that name into Shipping charges. how to do this? is there anything to do in admin panel or i have to edit the source code

Answer (score 0):

You can do in one of following way:

1. `app/locale/en_US`, check in `Mage_Checkout.csv`. Find shipping method and replace text after ,
2. Directly update on template file -> `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/checkout/one page/shipping.phtml` (replace [package]/[theme] with appropriate skin and theme, it can be default and default normally)
3. **Enable inline translation** and edit text on screen (Go to `admin > system > configuration > developer (under advance) and enable inline translation`